# HTMLunit onclick function with JavaScript disabled

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, htmlunit

I have been having trouble accessing a site with HtmlUnit. The site returns errors and site timeouts when I use 'webclient.getPage(URL)' with JavaScript enabled, but when I disable JavaScript I am able to get the page. The issue arises when I attempt to move from page to page, all navigation is done on the site in the form of JavaScript methods in the 'onclick' attribute of the HTML tags.

I have the JavaScript disabled while I get the page (originalPage), but I turn it on after getting the page and while attempting to execute the JavaScript method in the 'onclick' attribute. The JavaScript method is in a script tag in 'originalPage'.

```
originalPage = webClient.getPage(url);

webclient.setjavascriptenabled(true)

javaScriptCode = "javascript:getNextPage();";
scriptResult = originalPage.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode);
nextPage = scriptResult.getNewPage();
```

My code does not return the next page, but instead returns the same page as 'originalPage'. Is it possible that because I got 'originalPage' while JavaScript was disabled it will not function? Is there a way that I can choose while JS files get loaded when I call getPage()?

(I have verified that the JavaScript method does work in a browser)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that because I got 'originalPage' while JavaScript was disabled it will not function?

Absolutely.

> Is there a way that I can choose while JS files get loaded when I call getPage()?

It is possible but you would have to implement your own `WebConnection` and parse the text of the HTML before it is processed by HTMLUnit. Definitely not a funny task. Besides, if you would end up parsing HTML as text then there wouldn't be any need of HTMLUnit, right?

Another approach would be to translate the code of the JS you want to execute into HTTP requests and fire them manually by using `WebRequests`. Alternatively, and if you don't mind using a non-Java related solution, use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) which has better JS support.

Comment: Is there a way to force my JavaScript method to work without needing to reference the original page? Like a console in a web browser?

Comment: You have to execute the JS in a page